# MySQL - Converting phone words to numbers

Tags: mysql

Very much a MySQL noob, so please forgive me if I'm asking an obvious question.

My problem is that I have to convert telephone numbers from a text field to an integer. The text field has always been free text, so users have been able to enter what they want.  I've handled 90% of the rows (spaces, non-alpha etc.) but I'm stuck on translating the 0800 'words' - ie 0800PHONEME needs to be converted to 08007466363.  I need to translate up to 10 letters after the 0800 number.

If possible, I'd like to do this at the DB level

Any ideas/suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought: Make a temporary table with the letters and the corresponding numbers you want to convert to and then just step through the phone number one char at a time. <-- high level, I know.

Answer (score 0):

I wish i have the chance/time to complete the example, but you should get the idea:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73482/1

Just keep chaining the replace function for all the numbers.

Comment: You can put a comment with smileys if you want to make it prettier. This is just a way to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use a UDF (user defined function) such as [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) to find and replace the alphas.

Answer (score 0):

number 2:

```
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'A','2');
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'B','2');
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'C','2');
```

number 3:

```
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'D','3');
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'E','3');
UPDATE `t_contact` SET `c_phonenumber` = REPLACE(UPPER(`c_phonenumber`),'F','3');
```

and so on...

Comment: since it is a one-time solution to a problem, i don't think its a big deal to use an ugly-but-easy-to-do multiple 'translation' sql commands. unfortunately the mysql doesn't accept arrays as function arguments.

Comment: Thanks all,  I used the REPLACE for each letter - worked like a dream, and as has been commented on, it;s for a one-off so doesn't have to be too pretty